# Transforming from EPSG:25832 to EPSG:5684

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

I want to project some shapefiles from coordinate system EPSG 25832 to EPSG 5684.
The details of the coordinate system are as follows:

**EPSG 25832**
Projected Coordinate System:    ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  500000
False_Northing: 0
Central_Meridian:   9
Scale_Factor:   0.9996
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_ETRS_1989
Datum:  D_ETRS_1989
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

**EPSG 5684**
DB_REF_3-Degree_GK_Zone_4_(E-N)
WKID: 5684 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Gauss_Kruger
False_Easting: 4500000.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Central_Meridian: 12.0
Scale_Factor: 1.0
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_DB_REF
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_Deutsche_Bahn_Reference_System
Spheroid: Bessel_1841
Semimajor Axis: 6377397.155
Semiminor Axis: 6356078.962818189
Inverse Flattening: 299.1528128

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/download.html) something like:

```
ogr2ogr \
  -s_srs EPSG:25832 \
  -t_srs EPSG:5684 \
  output.shp \
  input.shp
```